# What's the standard way to create files in your hdfs filesystem?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I learned that I have to configure the NameNode and DataNode dir in hdfs-site.xml. So that's my hdfs-site.xml configuration on the NameNode:

```
<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name> 
    <value>3</value>
  </property>

 <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name> 
    <value>file://usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/hadoop_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
  </property>

 <property>
    <name>dfs.block.size</name> 
    <value>134217728</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I did almost the same on my DataNode and changed *dfs.namenode* to *dfs.datanode*.

Then I formatted the filesystem via

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Everything seems to be finished without an error.
Then I wanted to create a directory in my HDFS filesystem by using:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir test
```

And I got an error:

```
mkdir: `test': No such file or directory
```

What did I miss or what's the common process from formatting to creating files/directories with HDFS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it's so easy.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /test
```

was created successfully.

```
hdfs dfs -put myFile /test/myFile
```

works as well.

Answer (score 5):

Create a directory:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir directoryName
```

Create a new file in directory

```
hdfs dfs -touchz directoryName/Newfilename
```

Write into newly created file in HDFS

```
nano filename
```

Save it <kbd>Cntr</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Y

Read the newly created file from HDFS

```
nano fileName
```

Or

```
hdfs dfs -cat directoryName/fileName
```

Answer (score 2):

HDFS is a non POSIX compliant file systems so you can't edit files directly inside of HDFS, however you can Copy a file from your local system to HDFS using following command:

hdfs dfs -put /path/in/source/system/filename /path/in/HDFS/system/destination

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create multiple sub-directories then you should also use `-p` flag:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /test/another_test/one_more_test
```